# Border radius not changing for content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a border radius to circle out the green box you see however it's not working and I'm using `border-radius: 50%;`.. But I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing this correctly.

CSS:

```
.fa-circle-o:before{
    content:"\f10c"; 
    color: #4c9628;
    padding-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="rank fa-circle-o">yo rank</p>
```

what it shows:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: what browser are you using/want to support?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall   it's chrome browser!

Comment: I think you meant to tag @starvator ;}

Answer (score 9):

There's no border for it to work on because your content is a character.  Try this instead

```
.fa-circle-o:before{
    content:" "; 
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4c9628;
    height: 11px;
    width: 11px; 
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that class belongs to [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). That is a pseudo element with no content in it except for a Unicode character. Since there is no background or border you won't notice the radius. It also looks like you aren't loading the icon font, as the standard error square that is shown when there is no  character found is visible.

Once you load the font, it should look like this: [image: font awesome circle icon] and there is no reason to use border radius anymore.

**EDIT:** Your `p` tag also nees the `fa` class. If adding the `fa` class doesn't work, double check that you are importing the correct FontAwesome Stylesheet. Your full element should look like:

```
<p class="rank fa fa-circle-o">yo rank</p>
```